# Do Lutherans believe in a literal interpretation of Genesis?

Tags: genesis, adam-and-eve, young-earth-creation, lutheranism, literalism

Do Lutherans believe that the story of Adam and Eve and all the book of Genesis is to be taken as literal truth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For individual Lutherans, it varies.  For what the Lutheran Church teaches - the majority teach a literal interpretation.  There are likely a few more "liberal" Lutheran Churches and possibly synods that reject a literal account, but I have yet to find any.

---

When you ask "Do Lutherans believe", you're asking something that can't truly be answered any other way.  Some Lutherans believe in a literal interpretation of Genesis, some do not.

When it comes to official doctrinal teachings, you would still need to narrow this down further.  But you can typically determine a particular Synod's interpretation by finding their website and statements of faith. Most typically reject evolution and pronounce a belief in God's word as the ultimate source of Truth, and therefore stand by a literal interpretation of Genesis.

For example, [the Missouri Synod says this](http://www.lcms.org/doctrine/doctrinalposition#creation):

> Of Creation
>
> We teach that God has created heaven and earth, and that in the manner and
>   in the space of time recorded in the Holy Scriptures,
>   especially Gen. 1 and 2, namely, by His almighty creative word, and in
>   six days. We reject every doctrine which denies or limits the work of
>   creation as taught in Scripture. In our days it is denied or limited
>   by those who assert, ostensibly in deference to science, that the
>   world came into existence through a process of evolution; that is,
>   that it has, in immense periods of time, developed more or less of
>   itself. Since no man was present when it pleased God to create the
>   world, we must look for a reliable account of creation to God's own
>   record, found in God's own book, the Bible. We accept God's own record
>   with full confidence and confess with Luther's Catechism: "I believe
>   that God has made me and all creatures."

Also, 
The WELS website has [a section dedicated to Creation questions](http://wels.net/serving-you/wels-topical-qa/creation-questions/).  (All pro-literal interpretation) as are the articles at the [Lutheran Science Institute](http://www.lutheranscience.org/site/cpage.asp?cpage_id=180070232&sec_id=180015283)

Comment: Hm, strange wording in Missouri Synod's doctrine, “the world came into existence through a process of evolution” — they probably mean the living species, since that's what the theory of evolution describes, not “the world”.

Answer (score 0):

**Do lutherans believe in a literal interpretation of Genesis?**

In addition to the Missouri and Wisconsin synods, the Lutheran Brethren also follow a literal interpretation

http://www.clba.org/statement-of-faith/